# Error while using SonarLint and SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

With using SonarLint and SonarQube in order to analyze my project, I got the following error in eclipse console:

```
Error during analysis
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/sonar/java/resolve/BytecodeVisitor
at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.complete(BytecodeCompleter.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.JavaSymbol.complete(JavaSymbol.java:111)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.JavaSymbol$TypeJavaSymbol.members(JavaSymbol.java:349)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:193)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:201)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.Resolve.findType(Resolve.java:234)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.Resolve.findIdent(Resolve.java:294)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.resolveAs(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:340)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.resolveAs(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:319)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.SecondPass.resolveType(SecondPass.java:245)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.SecondPass.complete(SecondPass.java:234)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.SecondPass.complete(SecondPass.java:66)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.JavaSymbol.complete(JavaSymbol.java:111)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.FirstPass.completeSymbols(FirstPass.java:94)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.FirstPass.visitCompilationUnit(FirstPass.java:125)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:62)
at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:107)
at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84)
at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67)
at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:133)
at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:126)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:93)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:52)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:73)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:63)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:44)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.analysis.AnalysisContainer.doAfterStart(AnalysisContainer.java:143)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:125)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:110)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.standalone.StandaloneGlobalContainer.analyze(StandaloneGlobalContainer.java:118)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.analyze(StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.java:93)
at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.analyze(StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.java:83)
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.StandaloneSonarLintClientFacade.runAnalysis(StandaloneSonarLintClientFacade.java:60)
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeProjectJob.run(AnalyzeProjectJob.java:457)
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeProjectJob$AnalysisThread.run(AnalyzeProjectJob.java:127)
```

I'm also using eclipse neon and JDK1.8.

Comment: What is your sonarQube version and more particularly your sonar java analyzer version ?

Comment: SonarQube 6.0 And SonarLint 2.2.0

Comment: And what is the version of the sonar java analyzer installed on your sonarQube instance ?

Comment: It is sonar-scanner-2.6.1

Comment: What is the version of the sonar java plugin installed on your sonarQube instance ?